# Give a bound of norm in terms of norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Supppose $A$ is a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix and $x,y,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy
$$Ax=b$$
$$A(x+y)=b+c.$$
Give a bound on $\|y\|/\|x\|$ in terms of $\|c\|/\|b\|$.
Can someone give me ideas?

Comment: Hint: try to make the condition number $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ appear. For an upper bound, and a lower bound as well.

Comment: can you make it an answer? @julien

Comment: With this hint and Brian's hint, I think you should be able to work it out. And since it is homework, that would be preferable. Further hint: for the numerator, $y=A^{-1}c$ gives $\|y\|\leq \ldots$, while $c=Ay$ gives $\|c\|\leq \ldots$, whence $\|y\|\geq\ldots$. Treat the denominator similarly.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $A$ is non-singular, so $x=A^{-1}b$, and $x+y=A^{-1}(b+c)=A^{-1}b+A^{-1}c=x+A^{-1}c$, and hence $y=A^{-1}c$.

Comment: Thanks, I also got the answer above. But what is the next?@Brian M.Scott

Comment: @user81235: Use the equations for $x$ and $y$ to express $\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}$ in terms of $A^{-1}$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Can it be possible without $A^{-1}$? @Brian M.Scott

Comment: @user81235: No, you need $A^{-1}$.